# Automatically backup from qgis to pgadmin

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, database, data-backup

I have got postgres (pgadmin 3) + qgis link. And I think about next thing: how i can work with postgis layers, in a way that, backup file of my spatial database will created automatically for example every 10 minutes?
how can I set this up

Comment: Backup scripts are non-trivial and platform dependent: what system are you on? Is backing up your *database* (as in *PostgreSQL database [cluster]*) what you have in mind or is this really about using QGIS with PostgreSQL/PostGIS (e.g. if/how layer editing affects the database tables, how to upload etc.)?

Comment: thank u for explanations.  I use windows 7, qgis 2.18.15, postgres 9.6.7.

Comment: I import postgis data base in qgis (DB have N table, and it is looks in qgis like N layer). For connection postgis data base and import i use standart DB manager (qgis).

Comment: okay...still, what do you mean by *backup database*? to me it seems you might refer to how to save layers to the DB, e.g. after editing? point is, QGIS is a client accessing/manipulating respective resources exposed on the connected PostgreSQL server. database backups are part of general server maintenance and done via specific server level applications; to automatically backup your databases, one usually uses a batch file calling `pg_dump[all]` in a *Cron* job: [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows) would be the general workflow.

Comment: So, in any  case, i have to supervise saving of layers in qgis, case automatially creation of buckup file of database produced directly in postgres DBMS?

Comment: any edits on (imported) DB layers in QGIS will automatically be written to the DB table *when the edits are being saved*. backing up a database is a server side job.